# how to create next button for listbox in wpf mediaelement

Tags: c#, wpf

i am working with wpf media element.i created a listbox for playlist.the problem is how to control that listbox,i.e.next and prev buttons are not working,
i dont know how to move next item in list box.
can help me anyone
thanks in advance.

```
<ListBox 
     Margin="0,31,0,18" 
     Name="listBox1" 
     HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
     Width="74" 
     Grid.Row="1" 
     MouseDoubleClick="listBox1_MouseDoubleClick" 
     SelectedIndex="0" 
     SelectionMode="Multiple" 
     AllowDrop="True">
</ListBox>

<MediaElement 
     Margin="7,29,80,6" 
     Name="mediaElement1" 
     LoadedBehavior="Manual" 
     AllowDrop="True" 
     MediaOpened="mediaElement1_MediaOpened" 
     Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="False" 
     ScrubbingEnabled="True" 
     IsEnabled="True" 
     Stretch="Fill" 
     Drop="mediaElement1_Drop" 
     ClipToBounds="False" 
     Visibility="Visible" 
     OpacityMask="DarkRed" 
     BufferingStarted="btn_play_click" 
     MediaEnded="mediaElement1_MediaEnded" 
     MouseLeftButtonUp="mediaElement1_MouseLeftButtonUp" 
     Grid.Row="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

On your next button click increment the `listBox1.SelectedIndex` by one and of course you need to check for the boundary conditions.

Btw you should do this in your ViewModel instead of View. And you can Bind your listbox's SelectedItem with a property in your ViewModel.

Comment: private void btn_next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           
            this.listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1;
            
            mediaElement1.Play();  }

Comment: where have you bound the item to play ??

Comment: sorry i dont know how to bound the item.

Comment: give me ur mail id,bcause it's not taking my files

Comment: I may not be able to check my mail right now but you can edit your question and copy and past the content of your files there.

Comment: ok mail me at gaurawerma@gmail.com... I may not look into this now but if you dont find the solution by end of day today I may give you the solution.

Comment: By looking at your code I see you are not changing the **mediaElement1.Source** on **btn_next_Click** instead you are just calling the **mediaElement1.Play()**

Comment: how to change that source in next button.i tried but error generated.

Comment: If you add FileName instead of SafeFileName to your collection you will resolve this exception. But this will show the full file name in your playlist items. I know you will handle that with another collection

Comment: what is the code for changing media element source.i tried this but getting error.

Comment: You can google it. Do not get dependent on community for such questions.

Comment: i changed code like this in next button,mediaElement1.source=new uri(listbox1.selecteditem.filename); but error generated.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope U had written the code for mediaended event to play the next song.
The media element does't have next button by the design, but you can do it by adding new button with following code will help to skip the current song.

mediaElement.Position  = mediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan;